# Pillow: conversion from RGB to LAB not supported

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library, lab-color-space

I am converting a image to Lab color space from RGB color space using

`image.convert('LAB')`

But raises the error

`ValueError: conversion from RGB to LAB not supported`

Converting it to other color spaces (for example HSV, YCbCr, LA) works fine but raises the error for the case of LAB. I know I can achieve this using skimage or by using ImageCms, but I am wondering why this method is not working?

Comment: Please see answer here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/53353542/2836621

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert RGB image pixels to L\*a\*b\*?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52767317/how-to-convert-rgb-image-pixels-to-lab)

Comment: Neither of these solve this issue. @MarkSetchell that solution uses ImageCms, which the OP already knew about. This question is specifically asking why the .convert() function does not work with 'LAB' even though the documentation suggests it should

Comment: @arisbenjamin I agree - neither answers the question as to why the authors of Pillow didn't implement RGB to Lab conversion and that is why I didn't put it as an answer. It is just a comment that links to a perfectly good work-around. If you have some insight, or contact with the authors, and can provide a better answer, please go ahead and also ping me so I can upvote you. Thank you.